# Text to speech (pyttsx3) module not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I installed the packages mentioned for my windows machine but pyttsx3 isn't working. I installed pypiwin32 and pywin32 modules as advised. I also changed the version of the python package from 64 to 32 bits and even reinstalled my windows with little effect. I am repeatedly getting following error msg. Any suggestions?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\manas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 3, in <module>
    from comtypes.gen import SpeechLib  # comtypes
ImportError: cannot import name 'SpeechLib' from 'comtypes.gen' (C:\Users\manas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 123, in WINFUNCTYPE
    return _win_functype_cache[(restype, argtypes, flags)]
KeyError: (<class 'ctypes.HRESULT'>, (<class 'comtypes.automation.tagVARIANT'>, <class 'comtypes.automation.LP_BSTR'>), 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manas\OneDrive\Desktop\Manu's Python Scripts\1_Mastercode.py", line 8, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
  File "C:\Users\manas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\manas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\manas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\manas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
```

Comment: uninstall and reinstall `pyttsx3`, maybe that'll fix it?

Comment: I already have tried reinstalling pyttsx3.

Comment: 1. The above error occurred while importing library?
2. Are you running the code in jupyter notebook ?
3. Please paste the code which which threw the above error?

Comment: engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')       #getting details of current voice
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)   #changing changes voices. 1 for female
engine.say("Hello, nice to see you.")
engine.runAndWait()

Answer (score 5):

I just figured it out! it seems that this pip was recently updated and the updated version isn't working for me for some reason (tried everything - including different PCs, windows reinstall, python version change etc.). Although, the older version of pyttsx3 is still working OK for me.

My solution:

> python -m pip install pyttsx3==2.71

Comment: Works like charm!!